# Poisson equation in Jackson's textbook

Tags: electrostatics, classical-electrodynamics

I use a relatively new version of Jackson's electrodynamics textbook and I already saw that this part of the chapter is not in older versions. Jackson wants to show us that the Poisson equation $\nabla^2\Phi = -\rho/\epsilon_0$ is solved by

$$\Phi(\mathbf{x}) = \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0} \int \frac{\rho(\mathbf{x}')}{|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}'|}d^3x' \hspace{0.5cm}.$$

The term in the integral gets singular if we apply $\nabla^2$ to it. This is why he introduces a potential $\Phi_a$ with $\lim_{a \to 0} \Phi_a(\mathbf{x}) = \Phi(\mathbf{x})$ given by

$$\Phi_a(\mathbf{x}) = \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0} \int \frac{\rho(\mathbf{x}')}{\sqrt{(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}')^2 +a^2}}d^3x' \hspace{0.5cm}.$$

Application of $\nabla^2$ gives

$$\nabla^2 \Phi_a(\mathbf{x}) = -\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0} \int \rho(\mathbf{x}') \left[ \frac{3a^2}{(r^2+a^2)^{5/2}} \right] d^3x'$$

where $r=|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}'|$. The term in the integral in the brackets gives $4\pi$ when it is integrated over the volume, independent of the value of a. Until here I'm happy. Then he wants to calculate the integral above. He seperates the space in two parts: One sphere that has radius $R$ around $\mathbf{x}$ (with $R >> a$) and the rest. He also says that $\rho(\mathbf{x})$ doesn't change very much (whatever this means) in the sphere. The part outside of the sphere goes for $a \to 0$ like $a^2$ and does not contribute anything to the integral in the limit (I'm ok with that). To calculate the integral over the sphere he makes a taylor expansion of $\rho$ around $\mathbf{x}' = \mathbf{x}$ and gets

$$\nabla^2\Phi_a(\mathbf{x}) = - \frac{1}{\epsilon_0} \int_0^R \frac{3a^2}{(r^2+a^2)^{5/2}} \left[ \rho(\mathbf{x}) + \frac{r^2}{6} \nabla^2\rho + \, ... \right]r^2 dr+O(a^2)$$

I don't really know what happened here. Where is the first order of the taylor expansion? Why does a taylor expansion give a term $\frac{r^2}{6} \nabla^2\rho$? But it get's worse for me when he does the integration and gets

$$\nabla^2\Phi_a(\mathbf{x}) = -\frac{1}{\epsilon_0} \rho(\mathbf{x})[1+O(a^2/R^2)] + O(a^2, a^2\log a)\nabla^2 \rho + \, ...$$

What happened here? Did he taylor expand the integral? And what does $O(a^2, a^2 \log a)$ mean?

Then he says that we can get the Poisson equation by letting a go to zero.

Comment: For $\rho(x') = \rho(x) + (x'-x)\cdot\nabla\rho(x)+ ...$ wouldn't $\nabla\rho(x)$  be approximately $0$ at the field point - since the charge distribution doesn't change much - falls off like $(x^{'}/R)^{3}$ inside the sphere - and even if the field point was close to the surface $x-x^{'}$ would also be small?

Comment: For some details on how to perform the Taylor expansion and angular integration, you can see the answer to this question: [link](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/441818/taylor-expansion-of-a-vector-field-in-stokes-flow-about-a-spheres-surface/441855#441855). After that, I think it's a matter of performing the radial integral.

Comment: @CinaedSimson Why $(x'/R)^3$? And wouldn't this mean that we limit ourselves only to charge density's with $\nabla \rho(x) = 0$? I thought that he wants to prove the expression for $\Phi(x)$ for all $\rho$'s.

Comment: @secavara I will have a look at it later and let you know if it answers the question. Thank you both for your comments.

Comment: After performing the radial integration, expand around $a=0$ and you'll find a structure like this \begin{equation}
\epsilon_0 \nabla^2 \Phi_a (\mathbf{x}) = - \rho(\mathbf{x}) + \sum^{\infty}_{k=0} \sum^{\infty}_{m=1} \beta^{(k)}_m R^{2k-2m} a^{2m} \nabla^{2k} \rho(\mathbf{x}) + \log\left[ \frac{a}{R} \right] \sum^{\infty}_{k=1} \gamma^{(k)} a^{2k} \nabla^{2k} \rho(\mathbf{x}) \, ,
\end{equation} where the $\beta^{(k)}_m$ and the $\gamma^{(k)}$ are real numbers. The limit $a \rightarrow 0$ is then clear.

Comment: It limits the solution to a uniform spherical charge distribution where "$\rho(x)$ doesn't change very much".

Comment: @secavara The link that you sent me helped very much, especially to understand why the $\nabla \rho$ - part vanishes in general if you integrate a Taylor expansion over a sphere. If you want you can write your comments in a short answer. Then I can mark this question as answered for people who have the same question in the future. Thank you both again for your help.

Comment: @Lukas it sounds like you understand the solution. I'm still a bit stumped by this. Would you mind writing it down in an answer?